# Is it possible to set a default accent option and skip the accent menu?

Tags: keyboard

I often use the [accent menu](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh27474/mac) on my Mac, but for every letter that I use, I only need one specific accented option.

For example, for the letter **s**, I always need **š**, and never any of the two other options that accent menu offers me.

For this reason, I find it really bothersome to have to see the accent menu at all. Is there a way to skip it entirely and just make my **s** go to **š** automatically? It would speed up my typing dramatically without having to change my keyboard language layout.

Comment: For fast typing, try using the option key shortcuts on the abc extended layout.  Option v then s will produce š

Comment: @TomGewecke Thank you, I see this is actually explained in the link I posted above, but I missed it before. It's a nice alternative, but I am still hoping to find the long press solution, it would just make things simpler.

Comment: @TomGewecke After playing around with this, it doesn't work the same way for me. For example option i then a will produce â, but option v then s doesn't do anything for me. This is what I get: √s

Comment: You have the wrong input source.  You must activate ABC Extended (NOT ABC or US) to have option v produce the diacritic you need.  https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/write-in-another-language-on-mac-mchlp1406/13.0/mac/13.0

Comment: @TomGewecke Thank you, I've done this and it works. I'll see if this helps me write faster!

Comment: The full list of capabilities of ABC Extended can be seen at  https://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/mac/codemacext/